# WebDriver C# - Converting WebElement to String

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, enums

I'm running some C# Selenium `WebDriver` tests that a) pull a list of known link text from an Dictionary, b) pull the same list from the target website and then c) do a  compare to see of any on the webpage are unexpected/new/removed.

However, `WebDriver` isn't playing nice.

I have a list of Key/Values that represent the link text and link.

```
public static IDictionary<topNavigation, string> TabLinkURL
= new Dictionary<topNavigation, string>
{
    { topNavigation.News, "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/" },
    { topNavigation.Sport, "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/" },
    { topNavigation.Weather, "http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/" }
};
```

In the code below I then get the links from the webpage.

```
var locateTheLinkSection = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='nav nav-tabs']"));
var actuaLinkSetCount = locateTheLinkSection.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

List<string> actualLinkList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in actuaLinkSetCount)
{
    actualLinkList.Add(item.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("The links-text set on the page is:");
int a = 1;
foreach (var link in actualLinkList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"     {a}: {link}");
    a++;
}
```

The idea being I can compare the known links location (from the Values in the above Dictionary) against the links that come back from the Webpage. However, all that gets returned is:

```
The links-text set on the page are:
 1: OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement
 2: OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxWebElement
```

Does anyone know how to either capture the link text as a string to return it for comparison or how to convert the above to a string?

Thanks,

Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToString()` returns the string that represents the `IWebElement` object. 
Instead, use the `Text` property

```
foreach (var item in actuaLinkSetCount)
{
    actualLinkList.Add(item.Text);
}
```